# What is this variety of keyboard called?

Tags: keyboard

I remember seeing a video of a kind of novelty keyboard instrument being played.  Besides functioning as a normal piano/organ (I don't remember which), there were also keys that could be pressed to play all sorts of bells and whistles (physical objects— this wasn't electronic sampling or anything like that), which I think were in a kind of cage to the side of the keyboard.  Does anyone know the name of this instrument?

Comment: Sounds like one of those one-man-band custom, novelty-jobs... Assuming you don't have an image or link to the video that you reference?

Answer (score 1):

It is a [photoplayer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoplayer) -- a player piano with additional bells, whistles, percussion etc. frequently used to accompany silent films (hence the name).

[Video of a photoplayer](https://youtu.be/SF4BWllUEO0) in action.